# To prevent Null value entry in JSP page

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I've been working on a simple project. Getting data from JSP using text box, then using the Java in backend to save it in the database. I've defined the fields as NOT NULL in database, but the problem is when I click on submit, the data is saved in database as "", I mean it doesnt take it as NULL and it stored it as BLANK or "". Is there any way to prevent the submit action even if any one field is NULL or without entry? I know I can check it in backend Java, but I've to check every value as NOT NULL if I do by this way. Stopping the Submit action if anyone of the field is NULL is a decent choice.

Comment: You can use client side validation for this...

Comment: If you are using `html 5` then you can give `required property` to `input type="text"` it will ask for data until it ll not send data to server.

Comment: `"" != null` show your code

Comment: Try with client side validation with `javascript` before submit to backend, and it'd better to validate at backend too.

Comment: `NULL` is not the same as "blank".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using required="true" for the fields you do not want to allow to be empty. For example:

```
<h:inputText id="user" styleClass="txtinput" value="#{login.user}" required="true"/>
```

Comment: The OP is jsp not jsf tag!!

Comment: Yes, my frontend is jsp. But adding required="true" sorted out my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control the value being sent unless you use the framework(e.g struts,spring,jsf) specific tags and it has inbuilt validation on the client side.

There is nothing called as null on the form.Everything goes as String.
You have to write client side validations for Blank or "" and check for this value before submission.

If the value is Blank or "" then do not submit.